# Trying to compile gi-gtk-declarative

Tags: haskell, gtk

I am new to GTK, but not to Haskell. I am currently running Arch linux.

I cloned gi-gtk-declarative, and did a checkout of the release-0.6.3 branch.
I tried compiling with both `stack build` and `cabal v2-build all`, and both fail on gi-glib with the following error:

```
 > Unknown GIR element "docsection" when processing namespace "GLib", aborting.
```

How can I fix this? Is there a patched version of gi-glib?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an issue regarding version constraints:

- `gi-gtk-declarative` depends on `haskell-gi` (>=0.21 && <0.24)
- [Looks like this issue was fixed](https://github.com/haskell-gi/haskell-gi/issues/318) on `haskell-gi` 0.24.4

As you can see, the author of `gi-gtk-declarative` needs to update his dependencies.

As a workaround, you can run `stack build --allow-newer` or `cabal build --allow-newer` which will bypass the version constraint.